# Compression Criterion for $\pi_n(X,A,x_0)$. Why do we need homotopies $\text{rel} \ S^{n-1}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification, homotopy-theory

Recall the [Compression Criterion](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/the-compression-criterion/):

> A map $f\colon [D^n, S^{n-1},s_0] \rightarrow [X, A,x_0]$ represents zero in $\pi_n(X, A,x_0)$ if and only if $f$ is homotopic relative $S^{n-1}$ to a map $g\colon D^n \rightarrow A$.

It is a basic tool in basic Homotopy Theory, and therefore my intention is to fully understand the mechanics behind it. So I started looking at the proof carefully highlighting where does each hypothesis come into play and the following question arose immediately:

> Why do we need that $$f\sim_{\text{rel}S^{n-1}} g$$ instead of simply $$f\sim g$$

Obviously by $f\sim g$ I mean **an homotopy of triple** $[D^n,S^{n-1},s_0]\times I \to [X,A,x_0]$ which by definition is a a continuous family of functions of triples of spaces. **BUT** it's less than asking that the homotopy **fixes point-wise** $S^{n-1}$.

The only direction of the proof which (maybe) has to be changed is clearly the "easy" one, because in the other direction (starting with a function homotopic to the constant one and building another homotopic function whose image is contained in $A$) we are actually prove more than what is needed (exhibiting a homotopy relative to $S^{-1}$, instead of a homotopy of triple).

So let $f\sim g$ via a triple homotopy (this is the definition of representing the same element in $\pi_n(X,A,x_0)$ as written in [here](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/relative-homotopy-groups-and-the-exact-sequence/) for example). Now the same argument can be applied to $g$ to retract it to a point, and now gluing the homotopy from $f$ to $g$ and from $g$ to $x_0$ proves the claim.

**I don't see** where does the hypothesis about the homotopy comes into play. Could someone clarify this detail to me?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160173/proof-of-compression-criterion-iff-condition-for-representing-zero-in-relative/3500541#3500541 here or page 343 of Hatcher: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf